# Node JS UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY error while accessing https url

Tags: node.js, ssl, node-modules

We are experiencing error=`{"code":"UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY"}` when accessing https url from the node js application.

Issue seems to be related to CA cert file validation and the below solutions have been tried.

1)  node env configuration NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS added
    Result : Does not work
    Requires node 7.3+ to work

2) setting the cafile in .npmrc - “npm config set cafile=path_to_cert”
    Result : Did not work

3) Solution tried: Starting the SSL server with the root CA cert 
    Result :  Did not work

4) We dont want to use npm set strict-ssl=false

Node version used: v5.3.0 
npm version used: 3.3.12

Please let us know if anyone else had faced this issue or aware of any configuration that would fix the issue.

Comment: Those are pretty old node and npm versions. Even with a "workaround" I would suspect any new project to run across issues with recent packages requiring a more recent node version. Is there something driving a "need" for such an old version? Or are you simply using a "default install" on an old environment? Where possible/practical it would be advised to update node and npm here.

Comment: Yes, I do agree. However we are in the process of upgrading the node & npm version and were checking if there is any solution that may help fix the issue temporarily with the current version.

Comment: Probably not without the `strict-ssl` setting as you already mentioned ( or indeed using http instead of https ). You may not "want" it, but "old" software should not be expected to maintain modern standards.